# database record insert race condition with django

Tags: mysql, sql, database, django, race-condition

I'm trying to implement a list with maximum size using django.  For example I have a model like this:

```
class RecentView(models.Model):
    member = models.ForeignKey(Member)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    view_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=True)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('member', 'product')
```

Basically I am keeping a list of products a member has recently viewed. I want to constraint the number of record for each member to be within X. In other words, only keeping the most recent X number of products the member has viewed. So during a new insert, if there are already X records for that member, the newest entry should override the oldest in order to keep the total number of record for that member = X.  In my view I currently execute a query to first get the record count:

```
num_views = RecentView.objects.filter(member_id=<some_mid>).count()
```

And then I continue with the logic:

```
if num_views >= X:
    # Do not call create(), but instead issue another query to grab the oldest record and then update it
    ....
else:
    view = RecentView.objects.create(member_id=<some_mid>, product_id=<some_pid>)
```

This code will fail if it is called concurrently because this function is not atomic. I am not sure how I can do this using database lock as I'm not locking individual records, and locking an entire table seem to be unnecessarily a waste because this only affects individual members.

To me this should be a common situation but for some reason I could not find people with similar problems. Can someone point me in the right direction on how they'd solve this?

Thanks!
John

Comment: come on, anyone knows how to solve this problem please help!

Comment: nobody knows how to solve this?